# Recuperar valor serializeArray do checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um form com vários checklist. Ao clicar o array é salvo no textarea.

### Pergunta

Supondo que os dados já estão salvos no BD, quando a pessoa for editar, como fazer para carregar os checkbox que já foram marcados?

```js
$(document).on("click", "input[name='ar']", function() {
  let ar = $(".panel input[name='ar']").serializeArray();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ar))
  document.getElementById("arrayAres").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(ar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<button class="accordion"># AR 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" /> BVBV
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" /> GFGF
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" /> AFAFA
  </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"># AR 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" />GFHG
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" />JHJHK
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" />KILIL
  </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"># AR 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" />TYT
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" />FAFG
    <input type="checkbox" name="ar" />GJK
  </p>
</div>

<textarea name="" id="arrayAres" rows="5" placeholder="arrayAres"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi é esse `textarea` que você vai armazenar no BD né?

Se for isso, basta adicionar o campo Id em cada um dos seus checkbox (dá pra fazer sem Id, mas é recomendado tratar os elementos na DOM com id) e salvar os Ids também no seu textarea.

Depois, basta iterar entre os elementos do array que você salvou no BD e setar checked para true em todos da seguinte forma:

```
const textarea = [{"name":"ar","value":"on", "id": "check1"},{"name":"ar","value":"on", "id": "check2"},{"name":"ar","value":"on", , "id": "check3"}]

textarea.forEach(checkbox => {
    document.getElementById(checkbox.id).checked = true
})
```